# How can i draw NSView correctly to PDF context?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drawing, quartz-graphics, cgpdfcontext

I've got `NSView` and to this `NSView`I added some subviews which are subclass of `NSView` (named: `Square`). Squares are 50x50 on different positions. I want to render this `NSView`s with background color `Red` or `Blue` with this white background like on screenshot.

[image]

```
- (void)saveAsPDF
{

NSString *homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[homeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"plik.pdf"]];

CGRect mediaBox = self.bounds;

CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(fileURL), &mediaBox, NULL);

CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, nil);

for (Square *square in squareGroup) {
    [square.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
}

CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);

CGContextRelease(pdfContext);
```

Only what i've got is blank PDF file. How can i draw this squares correctly in pdfContext?

Comment: Have you considered just asking the view for its `dataWithPDFInsideRect:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call [CGPDFContextClose](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFContextClose) for the PDF data to be written:

```
// ...

CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);

// Close the PDF document
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContenxt);

CGContextRelease(pdfContext);

// ...
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFContextClose) notes that closing the context causes data to be written, which might explain why you're getting a blank PDF without closing:

> After closing the context, all pending data is written to the context
>   destination, and the PDF file is completed. No additional data can be
>   written to the destination context after the PDF document is closed.

Comment: I did so and continued without change. Pdf clean.

Comment: Anyone could help me with this problem?